# How to use 'chunky' (coarse-grained) zoom levels with Leaflet maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gis, leaflet

I am using Leaflet.js for desktop and mobile browser-based maps, and need to support a variety of map tile services. Some of these tile services are defined with coarse zoom levels (like 1, 5, 10, 15), and if I make a request for an unsupported zoom level, the service does not return a tile. (For example, if I request `service/tiles/6/x/y` when zoom level `6` is not supported).

Leaflet tile layers support `minZoom` and `maxZoom` but I'm trying to figure out if there is a best practice for doing coarse zoom levels, and if other folks have encountered this.

I found this post on GitHub that addresses tile scaling for unsupported zoom levels: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/1802

But I am not sure if this applies. (I'm not sure I want to scale or 'tween' the zoom levels... but if this makes sense and is not too difficult I am willing to try.)

I've started experimenting with this approach which gets messy because zooming can cause more zooming and I have to differentiate user-driven zooms from system-driven zooms:

```
// layer metadata (assumption: Levels is in ascending order of zoom)
var layerDef = { Title: 'Service lines', Levels: [10, 15, 19] };

// create Leaflet Tile Layer and show on map
var layer = L.tileLayer('://host/service/{z}/{x}/{y}');
layer.minZoom = layerDef.Levels[0];
layer.maxZoom = layerDef.Levels[layerDef.Levels-1];
layer.addTo(map);

// initialize lastZoom for coarse zoom management
var lastZoom = map.getZoom();    

var userZoom = true;

// handle supported zoom levels when zoom changes
map.on('zoomend', function (e)
{
    // get new zoom level
    var z = e.target._zoom || map.getZoom();

    if (userZoom) // assume user initiated this zoom
    {
        // is this zoom level supported?
        var zIdx = $.inArray(z, layerDef.Levels);
        if (zIdx === -1)
        {
            // zoom level is not supported; zoom out or in to supported level

            // delta: < 0 for zoom out, > 0 for zoom in
            var zDelta = z - lastZoom;
            var zLastIdx = $.inArray(lastZoom, layerDef.Levels);
            var newZoom = -1;
            if (zDelta > 0)
            {
                // user zoomed in to unsupported level.
                // zoom in to next supported level (rely on layer.maxZoom)
                newZoom = layerDef.Levels[zLastIdx + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                // user zoomed out to unsupported level.
                // zoom out to next supported level  (rely on layer.minZoom)
                newZoom = layerDef.Levels[zLastIdx - 1];
            }
            if (newZoom !== -1)
            {
                userZoom = false; // set flag

                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    map.setZoom(newZoom); // set zoom -- seems to not work if called from within zoomend handler
                }, 100); // delay call to setZoom() to fix issue
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        userZoom = true; // clear flag
    }
    lastZoom = z;
});
```

(Side note: I hope the reason for coarse zoom levels is obvious: it can get expensive to create and store raster tiles at each zoom level, especially for large geographic areas, and especially when used with offline mobile devices with their own [local] tile servers, limited wireless data plans, limited storage capacity, etc. This is perhaps not something you might encounter with toy apps and Google maps, for example, but rather with domain-specific and mobile applications in which space and bandwidth are at a premium.)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I found that the problem I was having with this code is that `map.setZoom(z)` does not work right when called from within the `zoomEnd` handler (it does set the zoom, but causes display issue with gray/nonexistent tiles, perhaps because Leaflet is still in process of scaling / zooming). Fix was to use `setTimeout` to delay the call to `setZoom()` a bit. However, I'm still really curious if anybody else has dealt with this, and if there is a 'better way'... (I updated above code to work with `setZoom` fix)

Comment: If it helps give more context to the problem: This is a COTS product, and people who buy it have complete control over which tile services are used (they set it up to use whatever they want).. so I have no control of or advance knowledge of the capabilities of the tile service, but I do provide a mechanism to configure the layers in my system (users can specify supported zoom levels, or simply min/max, for each tile service).

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a commit under review in Leaflet's repository on GitHub. It adds zoomFactor to the map's options. Maybe that's what you're looking for. At least, i think it will work just as long as your available tileset has zoomlevels which are (don't know if this is the correct technical term) multiples of the lowest available zoomlevel.

See: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/3285

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the link and your comments, but I'm not sure this will work for all of my cases. My example data may have been misleading with `5,10,15` because there is no guarantee of an even interval between supported zoom levels. I got my code working, but it seems like a weird UX to skip a bunch of zoom levels. Was thinking there could be a way to use the scaling that Leaflet already does when you zoom while it is waiting for the new tiles to load (even though it will result in a blurry image in some cases, it at least preserves the base layer context). I may consider extending L.

Answer (score 1):

The following (no guarantees, based on [this](https://github.com/nrenner/leaflet-tilelayer-vector/blob/dev/TileLayer.Overzoom.js)) should work with Leaflet v1.7.3 but probably not with current master.

It uses a `serverZooms` option to specify available zoom levels on the tile server as an ordered array.

Overrides `L.TileLayer._getZoomForUrl` to return a matching or the next lower available server zoom. Also overrides `L.TileLayer._getTileSize` to increase tile size in order to scale the tiles in between server zooms.

```js
L.TileLayer.Overzoom = L.TileLayer.extend({

    options: {
        // List of available server zoom levels in ascending order. Empty means all
        // client zooms are available (default). Allows to only request tiles at certain
        // zooms and resizes tiles on the other zooms.
        serverZooms: []
    },

    // add serverZooms (when maxNativeZoom is not defined)
    // @override
    _getTileSize: function() {
        var map = this._map,
            options = this.options,
            zoom = map.getZoom() + options.zoomOffset,
            zoomN = options.maxNativeZoom || this._getServerZoom(zoom);

        // increase tile size when overscaling
        return zoomN && zoom !== zoomN ?
            Math.round(map.getZoomScale(zoom) / map.getZoomScale(zoomN) * options.tileSize) :
            options.tileSize;
    },

    // @override
    _getZoomForUrl: function () {
        var zoom = L.TileLayer.prototype._getZoomForUrl.call(this);
        return this._getServerZoom(zoom);
    },

    // Returns the appropriate server zoom to request tiles for the current zoom level.
    // Next lower or equal server zoom to current zoom, or minimum server zoom if no lower
    // (should be restricted by setting minZoom to avoid loading too many tiles).
    _getServerZoom: function(zoom) {
        var serverZooms = this.options.serverZooms || [],
            result = zoom;
        // expects serverZooms to be sorted ascending
        for (var i = 0, len = serverZooms.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (serverZooms[i] <= zoom) {
                result = serverZooms[i];
            } else {
                if (i === 0) {
                    // zoom < smallest serverZoom
                    result = serverZooms[0];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
});


(function () {
  var map = new L.Map('map');
  map.setView([50, 10], 5);

  new L.TileLayer.Overzoom('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    serverZooms: [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 17],
    attribution : '© <a target="_parent" href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body, #map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks; the theory is sound. I'll test it when I get back to the office. I'm not sure it deserves its own question because the answer may be too opinion-based, but what do you think? Is using underscaling/overscaling (I prefer the term *tweening* since I'm not concerned with supporting levels beyond min/max) to show missing zoom levels preferred to snapping to closest supported level?

Comment: Don't know, I think both lead a bad user experience. I wrote this for vector tiles where in-browser rendering of scaled vectors would still be sharp. I think the preferred way these days is native on-device rendering.